# TestFight beta testing for internal testers - Build state is "processing"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, beta-testing

I've been using TestFlight for a while but this is the first time I'm submitting a build for beta testing directly from iTunesConnect since Apple bought TestFlight itself.

I've been experiencing a weird behaviour (or maybe just the Apple's expected behaviour).

I've added the user to my team (they've admin role), and I've selected them as part of the TestFlight tester in the dedicated panel. I've uploaded a build, switched the TestFlight Beta Testing on in the Build tab and selected the Internal Testers (just one in the screenshot below) I would like to receive that build.

Then...nothing happens, the state is still "Processing" (what?? shouldn't it be immediate?) the tester doesn't receive any invitation and I'm stuck. There's obviously something I'm missing here.

Beside, even if one tester has already been invited, the panel still shows "To start testing, invite at least one tester". TestFlight was such a good product once...

The two snapshot below show the state of my iTunesConnect panel. Any idea?

[image: Build tab]
[image: Internal tester tab]

Comment: I'm curious, why this question has been downvoted?

Comment: It's unfortunate how persistent this issue has been over many months. When TestFlight works, it's great, but when it doesn't, seems there is not much one can do, just wait a little and re-upload a new build. In my experience, if the new build is not available within 30 minutes, you will need to upload another one. Sometimes it does not work for hours, but next morning it works perfectly within 5 minutes. Hope they fix it up so it's actually reliable.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928471/my-prerelease-app-has-been-processing-for-over-a-week-in-itunes-connect-what

Comment: Clearly, Apple needs to hire some testers before committing their website updates.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It turned out that "Processing" a build, even if it is for internal testing only (i.e. the 25 accounts associated with your team) may take a couple of hours. Even if the binary has already been validated by Xcode and [Application loader](https://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/).

I'm posting this as an answer since I've found no evidence about how long the "Processing" state is supposed to be. Given the length of some of the reviewing process it could be seconds, minutes, hours or days so it's nice to know that in this case it lasted a couple of hours.

Now my console status is this one.

[image: iTunes connect screenshot.]

Comment: Thanks, I was also curious as to what exactly this meant and how long it would take.

Comment: I also see "processing" and "To start testing, invite at least one tester."

Comment: It's so frustrating - you bust your butt to get a nightly out, then hurry up and wait...... It doesn't help that the alert above suggests you add a tester, even if you have already added one - it infers you have missed a step, which isn't the case.

Comment: I am already waiting for 16 hours. Apple, whyyyy? Need good ol' TF back.

Comment: I am waiting for last 20 hours... what Apple is doing with my beta app.. really frustrating..

Comment: Almost 24 hours here now.

Comment: Snap. 24hours and counting.. This is totally unacceptable, considering the REAL Testflight was instantaneous. Heaven forbid that we should need our testers access to the app as a matter of urgency!

Comment: Same experience here from NYC.  Tried to increase build numbers.  No luck with that.  Uploaded at 4:30pm EST.  No problems in the past with this.

Comment: Disable Beta Testing switch and Enable again. Is a Bug in Itunes Connect.. I miss the old testflight

Comment: Took around 10 minutes for me.

Comment: Check your email. My endless processing task was the result of an error undetected in the validation process. iTunes connect failed silently but the email indicated I had an empty Swift folder. I'd removed a Watchkit from my cordova project and neglected to set "Embedded items contain swift code" to no in Build Settings. Other errors may behave similarly.

Answer (score 43):

Ok, here's the answer for the March 2015 people. I uploaded a pre-release build yesterday (4th March) via Xcode and the Internal & External Testing statuses are still at 'Processing' more than **36 hours** later. I even tried re-uploading, increasing build numbers etc. No joy. So I called Apple. This is what they told me;

**They have been seeing this problem happening regularly for those who have uploaded pre-release builds on the 4th and 5th of March. They've been investigating whether it's related to uploading via Xcode as opposed to via Application Loader, however they've been seeing the problem happening equally between both methods.**

So they're looking into it & will be trying to solve the problem for my particular case asap.

I think with those who are finding that re-uploading with an increased build number is doing the trick, it's actually a red herring and is perhaps more to do with having re-submitted at a good moment for the system.

I'll keep this thread posted as to how it plays out. In the meantime, if your pre-release has been processing for more than 24 hours and you don't fancy the idea of littering your app's management console with pre-release upload attempts (that can't be deleted), I suggest giving Apple a call to get your upload kicked into action.

**iTunes Connect Upload Helpline:**

Inside US: **+1 (800) 633-2152** From Outside: **+1 (408) 974-4897**

**UPDATE 6th March:** So, my original build finally came out of Processing. This took exactly **38 hours**! I don't think this was Apple fixing it, it looks to me that this was it finally sorting itself out.

Before this I also tried uploading new incremented builds via Application Loader instead and also while logged-out of iTunes Connect, as per some of the suggestions below, but this didn't make a damned bit of difference for me. Which brings me to the fairly certain conclusion that it just works because you're submitting at a good moment (or perhaps may even be related your geographical location (I'm London)) and no other hokus pokus!

The original Testflight rather rudely puts Apple to shame here. They really need to sort this out.

Comment: Been struggling with this the past few days.  Just got off the phone with the ITC Helpline, but not much help. Just wanted my feedback so they can forward it to their senior team.  I've tried uploading via Xcode Organizer and Application Loader, but builds are still in "Processing" state. Hopefully apple can resolve soon!  I miss the old TestFlight.....

Comment: +1, same problem.  Person at the helpline seemed somewhat unaware of the ongoing issue and suggested waiting 24 hours.  Hopefully this will be resolved in the near future.

Comment: I've been facing the same issue for the past two hours. Glad I'm not the only one. I bumped my build number and pushed with Application Loader and it processed and became the active build almost immediately.  The previous build still says processing.

Comment: I had 4 - 5 builds hanging, stuck at Processing.  Last night they all came though.  Some where hanging for days.

Comment: I had the same issue last Feb, I increased the build 6 times in vain. Next day, it went through on its own. Now with newer version, facing the same problem.

Comment: Selecting "Internal Testers," making a change, and saving seemed to immediately clear the queue for me more than once, as noted in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29013502/42619

Comment: I am facing same issue using Xcode 7, thnx @Geoff H for sharing u r experience

Comment: Same problem right now (November 2015!), it's look like they don't want to fix it. Shame Apple!

Answer (score 4):

Normally you should never see the status 'Processing'. Once the build status is set to ***Processing***, it will never be changed; at least in my case. (See image below)

The solution is to "**keep trying.**" Try either increasing build number or version number, and keep submit to the iTunes Connect.

I got it work in the *third attempt* with no processing time.

[image: Got it work at the third attempt]

Comment: I did increase build and version and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I found the following message from Apple (itunesconnect@apple.com) delivered to my Junk Mail folder. In the build settings for my app I set "Enable Bitcode" to No. I also changed the optimization level of the release build to None. After that my build was accepted and uploaded to the app store. The invite button became available for internal users at that point. Later I was able to get the app installed via TestFlight.

[image: img]

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "XXXYourAppName". To process your delivery, the following issues must
>   be corrected:
>
> Invalid Executable - The executable
>   'xxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib' contains bitcode.
>
> Invalid Executable - The executable
>   xxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib' contains bitcode.
>
> Invalid Executable - The executable
>   'xxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib' contains bitcode.
>
> Invalid Executable - The executable
>   'xxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib' contains bitcode.
>
> Invalid Executable - The executable
>   'xxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib' contains bitcode.
>
> Invalid Executable - The executable
>   'xxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib' contains bitcode.
>
> Invalid Executable - The executable
>   'xxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib' contains bitcode.
>
> Invalid Executable - The executable
>   'xxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib' contains bitcode.
>
> Invalid Executable - The executable
>   'xxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib' contains bitcode.
>
> Invalid Executable - The executable
>   'xxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib' contains bitcode.
>
> Invalid Executable - The executable
>   'xxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib' contains bitcode.
>
> Invalid Executable - The executable
>   'xxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib' contains bitcode.
>
> Invalid Executable - The executable
>   'xxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib' contains bitcode.
>
> Invalid Executable - The executable
>   'xxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftSecurity.dylib' contains bitcode.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Comment: What email address did the message come from?

Comment: @QED - itunesconnect@apple.com

Comment: even when there's no issues, iTunes Connect takes a lot longer to process a build with bitcode enabled than a build with bitcode disabled.

Answer (score 2):

i was struggling with the same issues as a lot of people say.

Infact this morning i upload a second Build for my app and state "Processing" will not go out in hours and hours.
I upload the second Bundle of the app to Itunes using xcode Archive/Uploader.

When i go out for lunch, i was thinking on "how Apple takes a lot of time to process a second build", instead of first immediatly set as Active.

Now i'm happy man, when i come back i decide to re-upload a third Bundle but using Application Loader instead of Xcode.
This do the Magic how the screenshot figure:

[image]

Immagine that the second build still in processing right now!!! 
Amazing Apple!!!!

So use Application Loader and don't loose important time!
Hope i help,

Answer (score 1):

I have been using TestFlight quite a bit, with no problems.  Then this happened to me yesterday (stuck in processing).   Perhaps some internal problem on apples side?

Answer (score 1):

this seems to happen from time to time and there is basically nothing the user can do about other than waiting. I have tried all of the above suggestions to no avail, then all of a sudden all the processing builds made it to the enabled state.

as of now (October 9th, 2015), it still takes up to one hour to process, but yesterday the situation was way worse, taking many hours.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me too in one of my builds. All my previous builds before that build were instantaneous. So I just created a new build (no code changes) and ignored the erroneous one. Once I turned on TestFlight testing on the new build, I got the notifications on my devices almost instantly.

Comment: Worked for me. Old build is still processing for 16 hours or so. Now I need to know why the heck do internal testers not appear for this build.

Answer (score 0):

What did the trick for me was to change the VERSION number of the build, rather than just changing the build number. I'm not sure but turns out, my every 5th build for a version has that long processing queue issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I have ITC open while I upload the build, that it never leaves the processing stage. Making sure ITC is not logged in until I receive the notification on my phone seemed to work.

Comment: I uploaded my build using Application Loader after I logged out from ITC, closed my browsers, closed Xcode and now all my Processing builds came through after 12+ hours of Processing during the night ... Did not check how long after my last upload they all came through.  Is this actually the ( temp ) solution?

Answer (score -2):

Add internal Testers

1. Open iTunes Connect and add the project.
2. In Users and roles add the iTunes connect users with their details with the Admin, Legal, or Technical role. An activation link will be sent to these users.

   - If the users already have an appleid associated with the mail then they will be asked for login, else they will have to create a apple account.
3. Archive the build and upload a binary for the app.
4. Add App Description and What to Test to the build. This step is optional for releasing your builds to internal testers, but required when submitting your app to Beta App Review for external testing.
5. Once you upload the build change the switch of Testflight Beta Testing to ON state.
6. The iTunes connect users will be available in User and Roles->Testflight Testers -> Internal testers. Enable the testers to release a build to them.
7. The users who are enabled will be visible when you click on invite testers in MyApps. You can select the users and send them a invitation.
8. The users will receive a mail. On click of open in Testflight, if the Testflight is not installed on device it will get installed.

Note:

1. If the external testers and internal testers are having the same email Id they will not receive the build. Also they might not be visible in internal testers list due to same reason.
2. In case the mail for Testflight build is not received disable the Testflight Beta Testing switch and enable it once again. This might solve the issue.
3. Once the users receive the invitation they should open the link for testflight using the Mail app.

   - Use iOS Mail to click the link in the mail, then iOS Mail will open Safari automatically.
   - If iOS Mail is not available, copy the link and paste it to Safari. For example, you can use Gmail to click the link, copy the link in Chrome, and then paste it to Safari.

Comment: I cleaned up your answer to use a proper list format. Take a few moments to read the formatting documentation next time. Also.. it's spelled "you", not "u".

Comment: @Xan congrats for helping out the community as much as you do, but there is no need to be rude. Not everyone is proficient in english nor they have time to read documentation. This was his first post, give him a break.

Comment: @budidino You realize that this post is nearly 2 years old? The original revision used "u" consistently, and that's something we need to correct in new users - I think I did so in a respectful enough fashion. I also directed the new user to proper documentation for the next time they post. It seems that you imply that I also downvoted - that would be incorrect.

Answer (score -3):

Firstly you must archived your app and submit it to store, if you submit it right you will get message like [image]

after it you will wait for few mints to see plus sign in iTunes connect like [image] by clicked + sign you will get you version. if your app take a lot of time in processing, may be more than one week, Go to "Resources & Help" in iTunes Connect. Select "Contact Us" and follow the wizard. I don't think anyone other than Apple can answer this. And this is what we have done in a similar situation in the past.

Comment: You are answering a question closed 1 year ago...and your answer is not even closely related to the topic.