# My prerelease app has been "processing" for over a week in iTunes Connect, what gives?

Tags: ios, xcode6, app-store-connect, testflight

I used Xcode 6.1.1 to upload a new version of a prerelease app to iTunes Connect so I could distribute it to my external beta testers. I've done this with two versions of the same app previously and it worked fine.

But this time, the upload was stuck in "Processing" state for over a week. I tried again (same version, new build number) and it's now been over 24 hours with no change.

The app passed validation fine.

What gives?

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079066/ios8-testfight-beta-testing-for-internal-testers-build-state-is-processing/

Comment: FYI, my app "processing" for 2.5 hours today and it's done now.

Comment: The only solution on this page that worked for me was using `Application Loader` to upload my build. It was the only build that finished processing after a 2-3 hours. The rest uploaded with Xcode7 have yet to finish over 12 hours later.

Comment: i take it back. That success must have been a fluke because  i uploaded 2 builds last night using `Application Loader` and they are still processing now 10 hours later.

Comment: I've spoken with Apple twice now. They said they are working with their itunesconnect backend engineers to resolve this issue.

Comment: "what gives"? something wrong as per standard English usage.

Comment: Check your email. I had an endless processing task, added builds that simply disappeared, but it turned out I had an error that wasn't detected in the validation (empty swift folder, I had to uncheck "Embedded items contain Swift Code" from Build Settings after removing a watchkit app from my cordova project) -- the iTunes Connect store failed them silently, with email the only record of the fail.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Go to "Resources & Help" in iTunes Connect. Select "Contact Us" and follow the wizard. I don't think anyone other than Apple can answer this. And this is what we have done in a similar situation in the past.

Comment: Done. "The iTunes Team receives a large volume of email daily. Your issue will be addressed as soon as possible. We appreciate your patience." 

Comment: Have you got an answer back from Apple? I mean a real one. :) We are suffering from the same issue ATM and wondering if there is anything we can go.

Comment: I had to call them on the phone, but I did eventually get in contact with the iTunes Connect support team. The best they could tell me after two weeks was that they were "still investigating" but I just tried uploading a new binary and it went straight through and is now "Waiting For Review". So, basically, just keep uploading until it works.

Comment: With a big company like Apple, a lot of times it's easier just to upload a new build

Comment: True, but the more people who tell them it is broken the more likely it is to get fixed.

Comment: One can hope... @combinatorial

Comment: This really shouldn't be the accepted answer considering how many woeful developers are talking about having this problem on this page.

Comment: I think it still should. If you look through all the other problems and answers it's clear that there are very very many different conditions that cause this issue and just as many potential solutions; it's also clear that most (all?) the problems are on Apple's side and therefore their responsibility to fix.

Comment: *True, but the more people who tell them it is broken the more likely it is to get fixed.* - Not really. Apple have very little love for developers, as it can be clearly seen by the level of tools they make available for us.

Comment: @SpaceDog trying developing for Blackberry, that's what no love is.

Comment: Actually one way to know whether your "Processing" is a true processing and not a fake processing that goes on for days, is to notice your app icon. If it is displayed, then you're good. If it displays the default icon (white color with lines on it), then you should up the build number and reupload.

Comment: It's 2019. They will never fix it. This is a mixed feeling of what I could do with App Store Connect (please replace HyperGAN with ASC): https://youtu.be/nA3YOFUCn4U?t=388

Answer (score 135):

We had a similar issue. Uploaded builds were queueing up and it simply said "Processing" with the popup help, “After builds are uploaded they will go through a processing state before they can be used.” Days passed.

Selecting "Internal Testers," making a change, and saving seemed to immediately clear the queue: The latest build was now active and available for testing. I've done this twice with two different apps now.

**Update:** At this point, all bets are off. It seems "processing" happens when Apple quietly upgrades iTunes Connect and there's nothing you can do about it.

On September 23, 2015 iTunes Connect didn't accept any uploads for nearly 24 hours. The "Internal Testers" trick didn't work. **Eventually bumping the version number (to avoid "duplicate binary" error) and re-submitting worked.**

The next day, Surprise! iTunes Connect was completely changed. I guess we were all looking at a dead site while they brought up the new version in the background :(

In our case we can still see dozens of "failed" uploads still sitting in the "processing" state. Oh well.

Some people report using [Application Loader](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.1.dmg) works better than Xcode for submitting builds to iTunes Connect. You can find it inside Xcode now, under the Xcode menu "Open Developer Tool" item.

Sometimes this works. Sometimes it doesn't. Your milage may vary ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Did not work for me. Apple needs to add a manual revoke option if builds are going to get stuck in the processing queue...

Comment: Didn't work for me ( 2 versions waiting forever ) but thank you - Apple needs to seriously get on the ball here, they're turning into MS

Comment: We currently have 5 versions, uploaded in around 2 hours difference, **all in processing**. Three of them on a different version number, others with a build increment. 9 hours so far without being able to successfully UPLOAD A SINGLE FILE. Would be great to at least have an error message. No way to contact Apple, as NON of the 'contact us' options apply.

Comment: We are having the same problem today for about 12 hours now. Uploaded 4 more builds with a hope to "push", instead ended up with 5 builds in Processing.

Comment: When all else fails, you can try calling Apple Developer Program telephone support: https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php

Comment: An hour ago all builds were finally processed and available for testing now. Sometimes you just have to wait... :-)

Comment: I uploaded 3-4 build from xcode7 and after 48hrs they still are in processing state. Also Selecting "Internal Testers," thing didn`t work for me :(

Comment: This isn't helping my blood pressure. :(

Comment: Worked for me. Man Apple!

Comment: All I did was add the word "nada" to the "What to test" section in Test Flight beta Information and I got past the "Processing" issue.

Comment: While I was reading this answer. It got approved. Thanks for information anyways! :)

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one. It worked for me in ~10 minutes, rather than having to wait an indeterminate amount of time for Apple Support to take a look. Of course, if I had re-submitted several times, at least a day apart each, and it was still hung up, then I'd submit the ticket.

Comment: After removing previous build from Internal Testing my current build through the Processing state. Thanks!

Answer (score 49):

The solution (as suggested by Apple Support in their response to a request for assistance) is to upload a new binary. I did this via XCode (same revision 1.4, but incremented the Build number from 1 to 2) and it processed almost immediately.

If you get stuck in "Processing" purgatory, increment the Build number in XCode, Archive and Submit to the App Store again. If it doesn't process within 15 minutes, try again.

Comment: Sending it again which increased build number and waiting 15 min did the trick!

Comment: reply from apple: "Reattempting to upload the builds and increasing the build number by an increment of 1 usually uploads the build successfully. Any build that remains in processing for more than 30 days will be removed from iTunes Connect."

Comment: I have found that even uploading the same binary (same version and build numbers) seems to restart the process and fixes it most of the time.

Comment: Unbelievable that they don't fix this. We are a year and nine months further, and it still happens.

Answer (score 31):

Had the same problem using XCode 7 betta-5. Fixed by unchecking "Include bitcode" checkbox during archive uploading:

[image]

Comment: This is the real solution. Disabling bitcode when submitting a build was the only way I could get a build not to stay stuck in processing.

Comment: @Dids How long did the processing take for your app? I've tried this and I'm still waiting for over 2 hours.

Comment: @mark The last time I uploaded an app a week ago -processing took about an hour. If you will not have a result for next 1-2 hour I suggest you to resubmit your app.

Comment: @Avt Thanks for sharing your experience. I've uploaded 3 times now. The earliest one has been processing for 4 hours. And I called support. They asked me to email them and they'd work on it, lol. So no help at all.

Comment: @mark What's their email? I have this problem too. I tried the solutions above but none of them works. I also called Apple Developer Program telephone support, but nobody answers. Looks like too many people are calling them.

Comment: @VinceYuan devprograms@apple.com

Comment: @Avt could not find this option while trying to export, was it removed from the final Xcode 7?

I Disabled the bitcode in the project setting though.

Comment: @Otávio I'm guessing that disabling bitcode from the project settings means that it won't be shown on the submission popup, so you should be good to go. I didn't disable it in the project though, but simply deselected bitcode when submitting.

Comment: @Dids I see. Then I'm out of luck since my project won't compile using bitcode due external libraries.

Comment: You can disable bitcode - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848208/new-warnings-in-ios9

Comment: I disabled bitcode and my app and it is still stuck in processing.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue. I tried making changes to "Internal Testers." No effect. I uploaded a new build using the Application Loader. Once the upload completed, the previous build changed from "Processing" to being available.

Comment: This fixed it for me! No drama!

Comment: How do you even get the Application Loader now? I'm using the Xcode Organizer, and would like to try my luck with the Application Loader, but can't find a download link.

Comment: This link might work for you: https://itunesconnect.apple.com//apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.1.dmg

Comment: You can access Application Loader by opening Xcode and choosing Xcode > Open Developer Tools > Application Loader from the Mac's menu bar.

Comment: This is the best solution. I just wanna add that you can reuse the same build file, don't need to increment the build number. Once Application Loader complaints that you already have the same build, just go back and cancel. It will kickstart the processing process.

Answer (score 13):

I got this message from App Store Developer Support (2016-01-02):

> Be aware that it can take up to 24 hours for a build to fully process
>   through our system and become available for use. If a build does not
>   finish processing in 24 hours, this can typically be resolved by
>   submitting the build again with a higher build number.

Not much of an answer (nothing about why it can take so long time), but it's the answer Apple is giving us.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar issue.

Yesterday, I submitted an app build (1.03) using Xcode, it was around 6 PM and this morning it was still "Processing", in fact it is still "Processing".

This morning around 10:30 AM I submitted a second build (1.04) using Xcode but that one also took too much time to change its status, so I submitted a third build (1.05) using Application Loader around noon, application loader gave me a warning about the app being too large to validate its API usage (the build is around 12.5 MB), it was just a warning so I submitted it and I'm still waiting to for it to change status (2:16 PM).

Of course, each time I bumped up the Build number. All the builds had Enable Bitcode set to NO.

**UPDATE (1:52 PM):**

The second build (1.0.4) just became available for TestFlight.

**UPDATE (4:43 PM):**

The third build (1.0.5), the one submitted with Application Loader just became available for TestFlight.

My conclusion is that their servers are slower than before... maybe the volume of apps that are being processed has increased and the load of their systems is higher because there are new things to check for (bitcode, watch os stuff, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Not to mention they are likely scanning for malicious code since the xcode breach came to light the other day. I still feel like a company as big a powerful as Apple shouldn't have these problems

Comment: Yeah the chinese knockoff version of Xcode may be the main reason the systems are slow today.

Comment: I used Application Loader for my 5th attempt. It was the first time I tried it after trying pretty much every suggestion in the question's thread. It is the only one that has successfully processed within a few hours!

Comment: I gave it a go with Application Loader... lets see how mine goes. I have 4 builds processing and reaching 48 hours mark soon..

Comment: Thanks @RacZo. Application Loader solved my problem.

Comment: And update on my status also. Uploading via Organizer on Xcode is still processing but I tried Application Loader and that seemed to work after 24 hours. A total of 4 days later and Im now able to submit for Review.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue yesterday. I submitted multiple builds with a variety of different settings. What finally worked for me was **submitting through Application Loader with no bitcode**.

I hope this helps someone avoid the headache I went through. Its been 24 hours and the apps submitted through Xcode are all still "processing", the one submitted through Application Loader was available within an hour or so.

Comment: This worked for me too. Make sure you check out the bitcode checkbox when exporting from Xcode. tnx @Seslyn

Answer (score 5):

If you run into this issue now, it's an Apple issue. They are releasing a new version of iTunesConnect. A bunch of my builds had been getting stuck in Processing these past few days. Today, they were getting stuck on Uploaded. Multiple phone calls and different answers later, the new site was *just* released and my builds are showing as Processing or available for submission. Though, they all have a yellow warning icon next to them. Not sure what that is.

Comment: Same problem here, the yellow warning does not contain any description. Any updates from your side?

Answer (score 3):

I submitted a new version of my app via Xcode 7.1 successfully. Then noticed the build was stuck in "Processing" longer than usual.

I followed Scotch's suggestion by increasing the build number, while keeping the same version, and submitted again from Xcode. This time the new build became available for testing within 5 minutes.

I was then able to select that build and clicked on Start testing. My internal testers received the notification emails and were able to test the new version via the Testflight app.

Answer (score 3):

I know its a bit late for answer but this is the first link appearing in google, and none of the above solutions were working for me.

I was having the same problem i.e after uploading build from application loader it stuck in processing. This happened many times, after hours of head banging I found that as soon as I close the application loader on my Mac, build status was changed :)

I hope this answer will help many.

Answer (score 2):

There is another question which duplicates this one. I posted an answer how I solved this problem. Maybe it helps someone else too:

[Anyone else's build for iTunes Connect taking longer times to process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745568/anyone-elses-build-for-itunes-connect-taking-longer-times-to-process/32746175#32746175)

In a nutshell: Build and upload with XCode 6.4 instead of XCode 7.

Answer (score 2):

OSX: Disabling include app symbols to symbolicate crash report did the trick for me. I will store the dsym and symbolicate manually rather then waiting for them to solve their "NEW" itunesconnect release.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using xcode, my app usually took 1 - 2 minutes to be processed but today I waited for 15 minutes. What I did was increase the build, keep the version same and archive it again. And it went thru within 2 minutes while the previous build still stuck after an hour.

My advise is don't wait for Apple, just increase build and upload again. Apple is too noble to admit their system has bug or mistake. Time is money.

Answer (score 2):

I'm loathe to add another answer to this already overcrowded question, but it might be of use to someone.

I found that if a "release" already had a build assigned when I uploaded a new one, clearing the existing build and attempting to select the new one always showed it as "processing".

However, if I removed the old build and saved then refreshed the page, the new build could be selected.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue for me...
Upload app archives from Xcode (7.3.1). Connect to iTunesCo with both Chrome and Safari...

- 20 august: v0.1.3 | b0.0.1 -> upload done -> never appeared on iTunesCo
- 23 august: v0.1.4 | b0.0.1 -> upload done -> processing on iTunesCo
- 23 august: v0.1.4 | b0.0.2 -> upload done -> processing on iTunesCo
- 23 august: v0.1.4 | b0.0.3 -> upload done -> never appeared on iTunesCo
- 24 august: v0.1.5 | b0.0.1 -> upload done -> **available 5min later**

The way it works has no logic... So I agree with @teapen:

> ...don't wait for Apple, just increase build and upload again...

Answer (score 1):

I tried changing the Internal Testers option, tried changing other items on the app details page, and tried uploading several new binaries (with the same code, only changing the build number) over a 2-day period to no effect. I also contacted Apple through the iTunes Connect support link; they replied in less than 24 hours, but only to ask for more info (most of which I had already provided).

Finally, the fifth build I uploaded, two days later, went through in the normal few minutes and I was finally able to submit my app for review.

Comment: Yeah. Seems the submission process is just broken somehow, I don't think fiddling with the app details page has any effect. Only thing to do is submit every twelve hours or so until it goes through.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue, I uploaded ipa via Xcode7 and it get stuck for 48hrs.
Number of times I mail to apple support but it won't work
so I uploaded ipa multiple times, but no use
then I made change in version number e.g. 2.2(33) to 2.3(1)
and it works for me. So try at your side may be this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a theory on this bug, which happened to me a few times as well.

What I think happens: if you are logged into iTunesConnect, then the web page will query the database for available builds. This querying could possibly interfere with the creation of new builds.

What I did was:
Log off from iTunesConnect on all your web browsers.
Increase the build nr in Xcode, make an Archive, and upload it.

Then: resist the temptations to log into iTunesConnect to check on the status. Wait at least an hr before logging on.

When I did finally log on to iTunesConnect, I found my binaries sitting there, and waiting for me.

Comment: Ah, the theory of duct tape. :-)

Answer (score 1):

So I experienced this yesterday (22 feb '17), I tried uploading the build via Xcode (8.2) multiple times, it showed `(Processing)`. Then I tried it with the application loader, still the same. I just had to wait for ~12 hours to have it spam me with processing done emails.

So yeah, it's not you, it's them.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this same problem for a few days and many uploads, seemed to work when I logged out of apple developer portal on my PC (which I use instead of my Mac to view the portal) upload the new version via my Mac and log into the developer portal on the Mac I was using to upload the ipa, seemed to work straight away after that, guess apple just really hates Windows or being logged in from a different computer is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue - However it was for a completely different reason then any I have seen online. I realized that my app did not have the proper iOS Provisioning profile associated for app store release. I simply changed the build number, validated and resubmitted. Within 15 minutes, the new version was ready to be added as a current build. The previous two versions I tried to upload are both still processing.

I am not sure why Apple does not tell you that there is an incorrect provisioning profile for the build to be uploaded, but this was my cure!

Answer (score 0):

Uploading the build with the Application Loader did the trick for me. If your current build is stuck in Processing, just create a new one with an incremented build number, and submit it via the Application Loader.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is the issue related to the app store. I have upload many build some time it takes time depend upon the size of the ipa and at which time you are uploading it to the App Store. Please use [Application Loader 3.0](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/tools) or higher to upload the build.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is Wait for some hours Approximately 24 Hours. Your issue will be fixed at once.
Apple is having bad times now a days. I hope they will soon fix everything

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with one of my apps, which is how I ended up finding this.  In my case, I uploaded two of my apps at the same time, using Xcode 7.1.  One of the apps passed through processing within an hour.  The other one was still in processing almost 24 hours later.  To get past this issue, I created a new archive with an incremented build number, and uploaded it using the application loader.  I did not turn off bitcode.  The version that I uploaded using the application loader took less than 20 minutes to get through processing, and I've been able to submit my app for review.  The version I submitted prior to this is still stuck in processing.

At least in the case of my app, using application loader appears to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Look for an email containing something to this effect:

> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSAppleMusicUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.

Where the missing key could be any of a range of permissions, and may be something you're not even using. This comes up often for react-native applications especially.

If you get such an email, follow the advice regarding the `Info.plist` key and then resubmit the app.

Comment: I have uploaded 3 build version but i did not get any email. 3 version not showing.

Answer (score -4):

The reason for that is that your build is missing something that apple servers is unable to determine.

to solve this, make sure you have included all possible configuration needed for your app, and make sure you have added at least one of the launch images for every possible resolution, that was my case, I add an launch image for every device and did works.

so, carefully check if you project is missing one of those settings or an image, and try.
thanks

Comment: It was a coincidence, if you made no changes and uploaded again the chances are it would have gone through.
Had the same issue up until few moments ago and uploading the same version finally worked.

Comment: @AragornSG: In his defense, you could probably apply the term "coincidence" to a lot of the answers here, even the ones with upvotes.

Comment: @newenglander exactly. There is no "correct" answer in this page. All of them are babbling of relieved and insanely lucky developers.

Answer (score -5):

I was facing this issue. It solved when I logged in into iTunes Connect in Chrome browser than Safari. My app was in processed state already.

Answer (score -6):

Cocoapods (`0.39.0.beta.4`) was the issue for me so I moved to Carthage.