# iOS Beta Testflight build still in process after 24 hr

Tags: ios, xcode, application-loader

I have uploaded the build on testflight beta on 2nd Sept 2015 (India) but it is still listed under Processing state. Dont know what is the issue with it. I have uploaded the older version on 31st Aug 2015 and it gets approved in just 15-20 mins. 
The code is same but just increament its build version.
Don't know what is the issue. 
Can anyone help me.

Below is the image which is uploaded but still in processing state.

[image]

Comment: Did u update the build number? and did you verify build before submitting to app store from Xcode?   It should never take this long.

Comment: @MDSingh Yes i have updated build number.

Comment: @MDSingh Now it is in list. Without doing anything just wait for another 24 hours. When i came back to office and signed-in with my itunes account. Now the build is available for Beta Testing.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know it may sound weird but it has helped me in the past: try making a change in the testers or any other field on iTunes Connect. It should free up the stuck version - [Internal testers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013502/211040)

If that doesn't work, try the other solutions mentioned on that post, but this one did the trick for me. Good luck.

Comment: Now it is in list. Without doing anything just wait for another 24 hours. When i came back to office and signed-in with my itunes account. Now the build is available for Beta Testing.
Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is why it was unlocked, but I added a new tester and the new build became available hehe