# Anyone else's build for iTunes Connect taking longer times to process?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I uploaded a build to iTunes Connect over 2 hours ago and it's still stuck on 'Processing'. This step usually takes less than 10 minutes for me. Anyone else experiencing the same problem?

**NB**: Yes, I've accepted the new agreements, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I had the same issue. The build just gets stuck at "Processing" and won't change even after days. This problem occurs when you build and upload the binary with XCode 7. Changing the version or build number doesn't solve the problem.

Solution:
Use XCode 6.4 to archive and upload the binary then your build will be ready within minutes. I still had XCode 6.4 on another machine.

It seems that this problem usually occurs with a major release of XCode. It's worth keeping an old version around. :-)

I hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: I wouldn't say it's Xcode 7. I uploaded a build on the 21st with Xcode 7 which processed fairly quickly. I've uploaded 2 builds now that are stuck on processing for over 12 hours. The frustrating thing is the reason is unknown. duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928471/my-prerelease-app-has-been-processing-for-over-a-week-in-itunes-connect-what

Comment: Yes, it's probably a combination of several factors, but it's indeed very frustrating. I uploaded my first build with XCode 7 on the 20th, another on 21st and yesterday I tried changing the version and build numbers without success. Today I uploaded a build with XCode 6.4 and it worked. Very strange.

Comment: Yea its super frustrating. I contacted them about it - will report back if more specifics are given =]

Comment: Cool. I also wrote a message to Apple yesterday, but I haven't got an answer yet. I'll keep you posted too.

Comment: Same here - Recently they've been taking WAAAY longer than usual ( as of 48 hours or so ago after the iOS 9 release ).  Currently experimenting with older versions of Xcode as well.  Right now all of our Xcode 7 releases are fully stuck ( none get processed ).. However 1 of our Xcode 6 releases of the same software finally got through last night.  It's taking FOREVER right now and this is not the norm.  We've created 4+ tickets TSI's and none have been responded to.  I've heard you have to keep calling them to try to get a hold of somebody, but we're trying to be patient w/ our tickets.  GL!