# My app is still showing status Processing after 20 hours

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I submitted my iOS app to iTunes Connect and after 20 hours, the status is still showing “Processing” under Prerelease tab. 
Is this normal or is it a bug or I did something wrong?
What’s my next option? 
Thanks  
Borna

Comment: I was experiencing the same problem the other day. I uploaded another build and it went through. Try some of the solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928471/my-prerelease-app-has-been-processing-for-over-a-week-in-itunes-connect-what) also.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone's having the same issue, including myself. I uploaded several builds yesterday and they are still stuck in 'Processing'.

Apparently, this has been going on for weeks: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17347

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not normal. The processing step usually takes 5-10 minutes. I uploaded some builds yesterday and they're still in processing 24+ hours later. The problem is definitely on Apple's end.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with Xcode 7. My solution was to disable bitcode on Xcode, recompile, create archive and upload again to itunes connect.

You can see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848208/new-warnings-in-ios9/30856364#30856364)