# Not able to select build from versions

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Today, I have upload a new build with changed the build number on app store. My build is available on versions tab but I am not able to select any build under build tab. I dont know what is happening.[image: Please check the screenshot] Check the screenshot

Please suggest me some solutions to resolve this.

Comment: Your build status is processing. You will be able to select build after process complete.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Have you any idea how much time it will take?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928471/my-prerelease-app-has-been-processing-for-over-a-week-in-itunes-connect-what

Comment: Don't just keep on uploading the builds back to back.
Just leave the state as it is for few hours and if none of them gets verified by then, upload new binary. That should work as it worked in my case.
Let me know if that works.