# Select Version to Test is empty in Internal Testing iTunes?

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, app-store-connect, testflight

I uploaded my App successfully to the iTunes store. But now i need to test the app using TestFlight. for this i added some Internal Testers. But when i clicked on `Select Version to Test` The latest build is not showing up in the list. I don't know why?.

I also verified my Build 11 on the iTunes. It shows that there are no testers available for this build.

How can i add Testers to Build 11 ?

[image: one]
[image: two]

[image: three]

Answer (score 1):

you can click (Not Available for testing) --> save , then (select version to test ) select your new version , fill the informations, then click save and start testing .

Comment: This just worked for me. Along the way I had to answer a question about export encryption, but when I did my latest build showed up in the list to be selected. My build is definitely not in the pending state.

Answer (score 0):

According to screenshots i think your latest build is in Processing state to upload.It take some time(10-20 minutes) to complete to upload on store.
once it complete

- select the build then click on save button
- after then open testflight your latest build automatically updated there no need to set again their.
- set your internal or external testers and press SAVE on test flight.
- if u already added testers press edit and remove previously added testers and save it. then again add testers and press save(it will send a new notification mail to the testers for the new build)

your new build is ready for testing.

Comment: The Build will not get added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue.  I Uploaded builds were in queueing and its showing "Processing" , “After builds are uploaded they will go through a processing state before they can be used.” .

Now you try this select a  "Internal Testers," making a change, and saving  immediately clear the queue: The latest build was now active and available for testing.

Update: At this point, all beta are off. It seems "processing" happens when Apple quietly upgrades iTunes Connect and there's nothing you can do about it.

Look at here for more info [My prerelease app has been "processing" for over a week in iTunes Connect, what gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928471/my-prerelease-app-has-been-processing-for-over-a-week-in-itunes-connect-what)