# Cannot select build for internal testing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to send a build for internal testing with iTunes.

I've uploaded a build (Build 4) with XCode. This build is stuck in the "Processing" state. I do not find any place where I can cancel it.

I've uploaded another build (Build 5), which went through the "Processing" state and is now OK.

[image: All builds screen]

When I try to distribute the build to internal testers, iTunes Connect only shows the stuck Build 4 (which is not available as it is "Processing") and not the latest one.

[image: Testflight build selection]

To make things weirder, the build 5 is available for External Testing.

Any idea on how to distribute this build in private testing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My prerelease app has been "processing" for over a week in iTunes Connect, what gives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928471/my-prerelease-app-has-been-processing-for-over-a-week-in-itunes-connect-what)

Comment: Yup, kind of similar. I've resubmitted a build with an increased build number which did not get stuck in the "Processing" state. The other thread ends there. 
But now I cannot select the new builds for internal testing, which is another problem.

Comment: any solution for this issue?

Comment: I don't remember how it was solved, sorry @HaimAbeles !

Answer (score 1):

Try adding new ipa with new Version number and build number