# My app is still processing from yesterday ,I changed the build version today and again uploaded .Today's Build is missing on iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, app-store-connect

My Xcode Version 8.2.1
I submitted my iOS app to iTunes Connect on yesterday but, the status is still showing “Processing” under Prerelease tab.

I found one link [My prerelease app has been "processing" for over a week in iTunes Connect, what gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928471/my-prerelease-app-has-been-processing-for-over-a-week-in-itunes-connect-what)

So, I changed the build version today and again uploaded .Today's Build is missing on iTunes Connect

Is this normal or is it a bug or I did something wrong? What’s my next option?
Thanks

Comment: I think your link had an excellent answer too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My prerelease app has been "processing" for over a week in iTunes Connect, what gives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928471/my-prerelease-app-has-been-processing-for-over-a-week-in-itunes-connect-what)

Comment: @arunjos007 I changed the build version today and again uploaded but build is missing

Comment: @ChanWarde I changed the build version today and again uploaded but build is missing , what should I do ?

Comment: @SudheerKolasani check mail you got some error for latest build

Answer (score 1):

It will take time to show your build on itunes connect. Some points you should cross check once before uploading again :-

1) If you are uploading build via Application Loader then check you version first. And I suggest you to upload it via xcode. Sometimes it happens binary get corrupt in "Payload" folder because there is some hidden files for eg .git or else. You should also check your Payload spelling for folder (Mistyping happens sometimes)

2) Check your email first , did you get any email from Apple. Sometimes it happens that our binary is not correct and further validation checked after binary upload. It shows in build section but after a while it is removed from there. You'll get mail regarding this.

3) Your build version should be greater then you uploaded previously.

Comment: @SudheerKolasani is you get your build on itunes connect?

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is normal. Me too faced the same issue. So i upload the new build with different build number and it processing completed old and new build also.

Comment: I changed the build version today and again uploaded but build is missing

Answer (score 0):

The Reason behind it is the privacy issue in plist,
if u are using any UIImagePicker or any extra component so u must have to add key to plist.

**Here is the some points to taken care.**

1> Check all permission like location,photos,bluetooth if extra so remove it.

2> Add this if u using UIImagePicker        NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
       Photo Library Access Warning