# ITunes Connect Prerelease Beta Internal Testing - processing

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

How long could take Processing Internal Testing app. I submitted app to iTunes via Xcode. My app is visible in iTunesConnect, however Internal is still "processing". I've been waiting 1 day and still can't test it.
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming.

Comment: it's problem with tool related with programming

Comment: possible duplicate of [My prerelease app has been "processing" for over a week in iTunes Connect, what gives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928471/my-prerelease-app-has-been-processing-for-over-a-week-in-itunes-connect-what)

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I'm having the same issue. I just resubmitted with a new version number... It's stuck in processing too

Answer (score 0):

Looks like iTunes connect has been having issues processing builds over the past couple of days.

[Check out this reply from Apple acknowledging the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28877871/79790)