# How to release testflight beta version to external users?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

Having submitted a beta version of my IOS App trough Itunes Connect and Testflight to INTERNAL users, and selected it for testing to EXTERNAL users, it displays "waiting beta app verification" (from Internal users) and I don't know how to release the app for EXTERNAL User. (see pict enclosed).
[image]
It did worked on past version but I don't know how ... times, upload from Internal users, approval from them (but don't know how).
Need to re-test then submit my app quickly, any help welcome !

NOTE : Apple displays help on old itune connect versions, and don't see where this can be done. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPXJ1.png)

Answer (score 2):

[Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html):

> - Upload a build for the app. See Uploading a Build for an App.
> - Add App Description and What to Test to the build. This step is    optional for releasing your builds to internal testers, but required
>     when submitting your app to Beta App Review for external testing. See 
>     Add Metadata for your Prerelease App.
> - Distribute the app to internal testers.
> - Submit the app for Beta App Review, and distribute it to External    users.

You need to have every build reviewed from apple for distribution to external testers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how it worked earlier, but for now

> All builds distributed to external testers must pass through an Apple review. While these reviews do not fall into the same queue as those submitted for App Store release, they can take time.

In other words, you have to use button "submit for beta app review" ;)

You can find guides here: [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/101790/ios-beta-testing-with-testflight-tutorial) or  [kyleclegg.com](http://www.kyleclegg.com/blog/testflight-and-the-ios-testing-workflow)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I was not sure of the process. My experience so fait : Internal review pass through an Apple Review of about 6/12 h. You say on your guide (link above) : "All builds distributed to external testers must pass through an Apple review. (...) they can take time. For Scrimp, the first review took about 12 hours, with two reviews since then taking just a few minutes, each." I already had some external review submission and it seems to be far longer even after several release. Anyway, I'll wait ! Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. According to my experience, the beta review process can take up to one day for the first time (for first submitted binary of a new app) or when you did significant changes to the app (there is a check button for this option). When you submit binary with only minor changes, the review takes significantly shorter time (minutes, one hour).

Comment: And there is no review for internal testing - as soon as you upload the binary, it is available for internal testing.

Comment: Thanks for the details. My app contains a database, so it is quite big and after an upload (from Xcode) I got the warning "big load' ... , it went to Internal approval (7h afeter) but take time to go to External. More precisely : 0h17 got Ack of upload, 7h41 got the app released for internal testers. I am at Paris time ... so if approval is processed on US timeline... could take longer during US night ?!...

Comment: There is only "processing" stage after uploading binary for internal testing, no "review" stage. Unfortunately this can take long time... Check this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079066/testfight-beta-testing-for-internal-testers-build-state-is-processing) on SO.

Comment: Received the release mail for external tester at 18:57 !  It works, but I can see only one new Tester the information "Notifed" (at today's date), so I don't know if former tester have been also re-notifed ! Moreover, Itunes' mail states "For testers to be able to start testing your app, go to My Apps on iTunes Connect and click the Send Invites button under Prerelease for the app." but I don't see nay send invites ! Any feedback on how it works for others is welcome !

Comment: There is a date under each "Notified" status - it shows when each user received the notification or when he installed the app. Basically you notify all users at once, but users can receive the notification on different date. Remember that notification from TestFlight app can be turned off, therefore some users don't have to receive any notification until they open the app.

Comment: I added link to Ray W. guide to my original answer, you can check it out, it's pretty detailed.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback. On your previous answer I saw a link to another topic in SO.... it seems that running beta test with TestFlight is not a piece of cake !! Perhaps the best (old) way would be sending .ico to users you have registered on your developper account (but they need to send their UDID before). Anyone interested by this, I can help.